# Is it possible to have a dynamic application launcher with different icons? 

Tags: 10.04, launcher, icons

(Ubuntu 10.04, Gnome 2.3)

Is it possible to have a dynamic application launcher with different icons?

My launcher starts a shell script to mount/unmount a hard disk drive and I'd like to let it change the icon of the launcher, too. Like an indicator showing the status of the hdd.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards